# what did Pgs mean in Third Reich Germany?

Tags: colloquial, abbreviation, technical-terminology

Brecht 1970 Suhrkamp Furcht und Elend des Dritten Reiches page 40, boldface added:

> DER AMTSRICHTER Ja. Ich verstehe überhaupt nicht, warum die Staatsanwaltschaft da ein Verfahren eingeleitet hat, offen gestanden.

> DER STAATSANWALT Wieso? Der Fall hat im Viertel unliebsames Aufsehen erregt. Sogar **Pgs** haben eine Untersuchung für angezeigt gehalten.

Just guessing, "Parteigesellschaft"? "Parteigenossenschaft"? Meaning the Nazis?

The context: Augsburg, 1934. Three SA brownshirts apparently invaded the shop and home of a Jewish jeweler, injured him physically, and afterward a large amount of valuable jewelry was missing. I think the Amtsrichter is trying to figure out how to navigate the situation without ending up in a KZ himself. He wishes the issue would just go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the time's Nazi jargon, "Pg." or similar [stood for "Parteigenosse"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genosse#Politische_Bedeutung_in_der_NSDAP), meaning "comrade in the party" or basically "party member" (of the NSDAP). During the Third Reich, that was a badge of honor or at least something like "that's a decent citizen". After 1945 not so much, obviously. Today, the term "Parteigenosse" is used more or less neutrally for whichever party.

As you wrote, in Brecht's piece the judge basically wants the case to go away, without anybody looking too closely into it. But the prosecutor argues that it caused quite an unwelcome stir in the neighborhood. Even some "Parteigenossen" think that it warranted a formal investigation.

Comment: Do you have examples for the current use of _Parteigenosse_? I would have thought that the current term for a fellow member of a party is _Parteifreund_. _Parteigenosse_ is tied to the NSDAP, in my ears. But I might be wrong and relevant examples would change my mind.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Du scheinst kein SPD-Mitglied zu sein ;)

Comment: @tofro Bei der SPD sagt man, meines Wissens, _Genosse_, aber nicht unbedingt _Parteigenosse_.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach For example "... somit Parteigenosse des Stadtoberhaupts ..." [here](https://www.pnn.de/potsdam/schule-in-der-waldstadt-spd-teils-gegen-rathausplan/28429594.html) or "Parteigenosse von ermordetem Ex-Premier gewinnt Wahl" (in the page title [here](https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/article239845633/Japan-Parteigenosse-von-ermordetem-Ex-Premier-gewinnt-Wahl.html)) or "die eine Parteigenossin und ein Parteigenosse (...) geführt hatten" [here](https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/mecklenburg-vorpommern/Rostocks-Sozialsenator-faellt-mit-zweifelhaftem-Tweet-auf,bockhahnlinke100.html).

Comment: Eine Suche nach "Parteigenosse" unter "Nachrichten" in einer Suchmaschine ergibt für mich, dass Journalisten das heute in der Außensicht tatsächlich für alle Parteien benutzen.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach "Genosse" wird meines Wissens innerhalb der SPD, also zwischen Mitgliedern verwendet. Von außerhalb gibt es durchaus schon mal ein "Parteigenosse". Ich will nicht ausschließen, dass der Begriff eher bei linken Parteien, nicht nur bei der SPD verwendet wird. Aber wenn mich die Erinnerung nicht trügt, kommt es auch auf der rechten Seite des politischen Spektrums vor.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Danke für die Beispiele!

Comment: Nowadays, how is "Pg" or "Pgs" pronounced? Does one spell out the letters P, G or does one pronounce it as a single word? "pog"?

Comment: @JacobWegelin I think abbreviations are usually spelled out, but in this informal context I assume you'd just say "Pehgehs"